# Swift dictionary change the variable of the value

Tags: ios, swift

I'm sorry if it's already discussed, but i don't find the solution

I have a struct:

```
struct Point2D
{
    var x: Double = 0.0
    var y: Double = 0.0
}
```

And I have a class also:

```
class Letter
{   
    var points3D: Dictionary<String,Point3D> = [:]
    var points2D: Dictionary<String,Point2D> = [:]
    var edges: Dictionary<String,Edge> = [:]
}
```

In some view:

```
class GraphicView: UIView {
   var letter:Letter!

   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      for (name,point3d) in letter.points3D {
            //Says String isn't convertable to DictionaryIndex<String,Point2D> 
            letter.points2D[name]!.x = point3d.x * (perspective / (perspective - point3d.z)) + imageWidth/2
            letter.points2D[name]!.y = point3d.y * (perspective / (perspective - point3d.z)) + imageHeight/2
        }
}
```

I'm trying to find some value for key (I know it exists) and change variables of this value to another. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `perspective`, `imageWidth` or `imageHeight` is not `Double`?

try:

```
class GraphicView: UIView {
   var letter:Letter!

   override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
      for (name,point3d) in letter.points3D {
            letter.points2D[name]!.x = point3d.x * (Double(perspective) / (Double(perspective) - point3d.z)) + Double(imageWidth)/2
            letter.points2D[name]!.y = point3d.y * (Double(perspective) / (Double(perspective) - point3d.z)) + Double(imageHeight)/2
        }
}
```